# Rails Foundation topbar active item highlight

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am using zurb foundation in my rails app and have set my topbar as shown in the docs at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

Here is the truncated code:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
  <ul class="right">        
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="http://xyz.dev">Home</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

However, with the above code the the active menu item of `Home` is not getting highlighted.

When debugging using google chrome dev tools, I find that the style that is being applied is from the below section

```
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 45px;
  background: #333333;
}
```

Generally, to highlight the currently active link, the below code should be applicable:

```
.top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
  background: #008cba;
  color: white;
}
```

I am not sure why the priority of css styling is changing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rule is taking precedence because it has more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the second. I suggest overriding this with the same properties as foundation's active class, just using a more specific selector in your own stylesheet. You can use:

```
.top-bar-section ul.right li.active > a { /* 0, 0, 3, 3 */ 
    background: #008cba;
    color: white;
}
```

This allows the above selector to take precedence when using `.active` (regardless of order):

```
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) /* 0, 0, 3, 2 */
```